# Offensive and vulgar tags -- merge

Tags: discussion

We have tags [[offensive-language]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language) and [[vulgarity]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulgarity).  The former has synonyms including [vulgar].

I've [suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/offensive-language/synonyms) that [vulgarity] should be a synonym for [offensive language].

Comment: Vote here: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/offensive-language/synonyms

Comment: A piece of text can be offensive without being vulgar, and vice-versa.  I don't see them as synonymous.

Comment: @Chenmunka I agree. But we're starting from a position that already confuses the two, so in a way I'm proposing one big mess instead of two smaller overlapping messes

Answer (score 1):

The **vulgarity** tag's description is

> Use this tag for questions that relate to questioning whether certain words are taboo or if your question relates to the level of appropriateness of a word or its possibility to offend in certain situations and contexts.

The **offensive-language** tag's description is

> This tag is for questions about offensive language. It is for questions about words or phrases that could be considered offensive. If reason of offensiveness is belittling or painting a negative light instead of 'just offending' CONSIDER using the tag PEJORATIVE-LANGUAGE.

There is a difference between using language which could be considered offensive and asking whether certain words are taboo. With the former one *knows* that there are people who do consider the language offensive, even if there are also those who do not. The latter suggests that you *think* the words might be offensive, but there is no certainty that anyone actually finds them so.

There is enough of a difference there for these not to be synonyms.

Comment: That's a fair point, though it suggests further tidying up is required as *vulgar* and *vulgarity* are currently on different sides of the divide. Also *pejorative language* maps back to *offensive language*, which makes a nonsense of the current tag wording (a synonym I disagree with, by the way).

Comment: I don't know how much can be done with existing synonyms, like desynonymising. But existing issues are not really a reason to add to them!

Comment: You're right there. While I accept that there's a distinction in the tag wikis I think there's so much overlap that most questions tagged  *vulgarity* could also be tagged *offensive language* based on "It is for questions about words or phrases that could be considered offensive" from the latter's wiki

Comment: @ChrisH NVZ's protip: Tags are a mess. They always are.

Comment: @NVZ perhaps so, but they are much much messier on ELL. It is impossible to use the tags there to search for duplicates, at least on EL&U the tags make this task a little easier